# Load .txt file via jquery based on weekdays

Tags: javascript, css

I searched this and several websites to find an answer for this, but didn't find any that could help with my problem, so here we go.

Basicly what i want to do is load a .txt file into my website via jquery.

This i'm able to do with a simple get command.

i found a solution that does the job for me online as so

```
<span id="dynamicdate">THIS SHOULD BE DYNAMIC</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
   $.get("menu/menudeldia.txt", function(data) {
      $("#dynamicdate").html(data);
   });
});
</script>
```

Now every day of the week is should load another text file or other part of the file.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is use Javascript's Date object and the getDay() function. Further information on that is is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

And then use a switch case statement to decide what text file to load based on the day of the week:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Something along these lines:

```
var today = new Date();
var day = today.getDay();

switch(day) {
  case(0):
    file = "/sunday.txt";
    break;
  case(1):
    file = "/monday.txt";  
    break;
  default: 
    file = "/otherday.txt";
    break;
}

$.get(file, function(data) {
  $("#dynamicdate").html(data);
});
```

Comment: gave you an idea of how to put this together